# Multiple Mootools Carousels on a single page

Tags: mootools, carousel

I have been looking around online for a MooTools carousel plug-in that will allow me to have multiple on a single page.

I currently have [this one](http://tbela99.github.com/carousel/Demos/horizontal.html) working successfully for a single carousel, but it doesn't seem to allow multiple on a page.

Am I doing something wrong with the plug-in mentioned, or is there a recommended plug-in that exists somewhere?